# Adding dynamic position to the element I am appending

Tags: jquery

I am trying to generate a `div on click` of a body and want to assign a position dynamically.The `div` should be generated where the user will click.

I am getting the position of the click but don't know how to assign it to the currently generated element.

Thanks for the Help in advance.

```js
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').append("<div class='bubble'></div>");
    console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    $('bubble').css({
        'top': e.pageX,
        'left': e.pageY
    });

});
```

```css
*{ transition: all 0.5s ease; }
html,
body{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.bubble{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #99c8fd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>Click here</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a jQuery object using [`jQuery(html,attributes)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) with set CSS rules then append it.

```js
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  var elem = $("<div />", {
    "class": "bubble"
  }).css({
    'top': e.pageY,
    'left': e.pageX
  });
  $('body').append(elem);
});
```

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.bubble {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #99c8fd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>Click here</body>
```

Comment: No problem: You never know... he may actually have meant it to be sideways :)